# Probability that two persons meet

Tags: probability

Given that two persons have to meet tomorrow between 9 to 10. A person will wait for 20 minutes upon arrival for the other person. What is the probability that they meet?
the idea is as follow:

**UPDATe**

Consider graph whose x-axis is the possible times in which the first person arrives, the y-axis is the possible times in which the second person arrives. So the region in the plan correspond to the event space is the square $\{9\leq x \leq 10, 9 \leq y \leq 10\}$. We can move the square so that it "start" at the orrigin, then the region in which they meet is between the line intersecting "((40mins, 20mins),(60min,40min))" and the line intersecting "(0 min,20min), (20min,40min))" here, I wrote using unit minute, but it can be easily translated to the actual coordinate.  Ok the area outside of the lines and inside the square is $2*\frac{40*40}{2}=160$, the total area is $60*60=360$. So answer is $1-\frac{160}{360}=\frac{4}{9}$.

Comment: thoughts, attempts, relevance.

Comment: is $\frac{4}{9}$ a solution?

Comment: you misinterpret the use of this site, not simply a is this the answer site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that the first person arrives during the first (2/3) hour is 2/3. [60/20 = 3, so dividing the hours by this]

Then, that person will wait for (1/3) hour. The probability that he arrives during the last (1/3) hour is 1/3

Thus, on average he'll wait for 1/6 hour.
Now, the first person will wait for (2/3)(1/3) + (1/3)(1/6) = 5/18.

Similarly, the probability that the next person arrives (when the first person is waiting is 5/18. 
Now considering the vice versa of the situation, i.e. the second person comes first. Hence, the total probability of them meeting is 5/18 + 5/18 = 5/9.

Considering, one man must arrive before another.

Comment: A question neither showing context nor any effort should not be answered.

Comment: Really sorry. Just trying to help and know what the actual answer is. I am not 100% sure on my solution, that's why I just shared my approach.